# How could I find a call of a function thats only referenced inside a vftable?

Tags: ida, disassembly, c++, game-hacking

So I have this function which I'm trying to figure out the arguments to.

[image]

However, all the xrefs of it point to a VFTable.

[image]

How would I find a call for this function?

Answer (score 1):

From that screenshot you can see the base of the vtable is referenced - likely when the object is constructed. You'll need to keep an eye on where the object gets stored and follow it through the code